# Importing files in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

My directory structure looks like this:

```
web/
  js/
    Test.js
mobile
  index.android.js
```

In `index.android.js`, I added `import Test from '../web/js/Test`. However, I get this error:

```
(node:590) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 12):
UnableToResolveError:
Unable to resolve module `../web/js/Test.js` from `/mnt/d/.../mobile/index.android.js`:
Directory /mnt/d/.../web/js/Test.js doesn't exist
```

I tried rerunning `react-native start` and it still didn't work. I don't have Watchman installed, but I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to reuse your React web code in React Native? Does React Native allow you to import a js file from anywhere outside your project root directory and its nested folders? It seems like you are missing the closing single-quote for the import you mentioned, although that might have been a typo in your part? Another question is how Test is defined. Are you exporting that component correctly? We need further information to determine what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

1) In package.json in mobile folder add as dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
   //...your deps here +
   "commonWebAndMobileDeps": "file:../web/js/common"
}
```

2) Make sure Test.js is in `web/js/common`

3) In mobile folder run `npm install`

4) In mobile import it with:

```
import Test from 'commonWebAndMobileDeps/Test'
```